# How to Fix embedded video full screen button not clickable on Wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, embed, video-player

Added video embed code inside wordpress post:

```
<iframe src="https://www.example.com/embed-blabla.html" width="640" 
height="480" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="NO"><span data-mce-type="bookmark" style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; overflow: hidden; line-height: 0;" class="mce_SELRES_start"></span></iframe>
```

But the full screen button not working (not clickable) on video player(JW 6).
How to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the allowfullscreen attribute on iframe tag